# Couldn't fetch remote media on Cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloudinary

I would like to overlay remote media on smaple.jpg in Cloudinary. But `:type=>"fetch"` wouldn't work and the image wouldn't show up.

Just read [Document](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/fetch_remote_images), but this doesn't apply to the current case.

```
<%= cl_image_tag(
  "ogp.png", 
  :transformation=>[
    {:color=> '#fff', :overlay=>{:color=> "#ffffff", :font_family => 'Open Sans', :font_size=> 20, :text_align=> 'center', :text=> @channel.user.name},},
    {:flags=>"layer_apply", :gravity=>"north", :y=>90},
    {:type=> 'fetch'},
    {:overlay=> Base64.encode64('https://[PUBLI IMAGE URL].jpg'), :type=>"fetch"},
  ],
) %>

=> https://res-4.cloudinary.com/remotehour/image/upload/co_rgb:fff,l_text:Open%20Sans_20_center:Shun/fl_layer_apply,g_north,y_90/l_aHRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXwMC5qcGc=/sampple.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the base64 encoded version, you would need to do specify image with the *url* parameter. You don't need to specify `fetch` since the SDK will automatically take care of it. You can find an example [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/layers#remote_image_overlays).

Here's the code in Python as I'm not too familiar with PHP.

```py
import cloudinary

resp = cloudinary.CloudinaryImage('sample').image(
    transformation = [
        {"overlay": {"text": "hi",'font_family': 'roboto', 'font_size':30},'gravity': 'north_west','x':20,'y':20,'color':'blue'},
        {"overlay": {'url': 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/3948546/pexels-photo-3948546.png'},'gravity':'south_east','width':250,'height':250,'crop':'fill','x':10,'y':10}
    ]
)
print(resp)
```

This will generate an image with a text at top left and the overlay image at bottom right.

[image: sample image]

Output URL: https://res.cloudinary.com/akshayranganath/image/upload/co_blue,g_north_west,l_text:roboto_30:hi,x_20,y_20/c_fill,g_south_east,h_250,l_fetch:aHR0cHM6Ly9pbWFnZXMucGV4ZWxzLmNvbS9waG90b3MvMzk0ODU0Ni9wZXhlbHMtcGhvdG8tMzk0ODU0Ni5wbmc=,w_250,x_10,y_10/sample

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer. It would be really helpful!! But the error occurs `Must supply public_id for resource_type layer_parameter` when trying `<%= cl_image_tag("sample.jpg", :overlay=>{:url=>"https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/logos/cloudinary_full_logo_white_small.png"}) %>`

Comment: You cannot use `url` inside `overlay`. You need to provide the resource's public_id, like this:


`cl_image_tag("sample.jpg", :overlay=>"overlayPublicId")` 


Please check the relevant doc - 
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/layers